# getting the links from webpage

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-scraping

I have a URL which I want to collect the links and push it into an array. but it writes all together inside one array. '.cb-content' is the class of the div which has the links'

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const request = require('request')
request(url, (error, response, body) => {
  if (!error) {
    let linksList = []
    $ = cheerio.load(body);
    const bodyHtml = $('.cb-content')
    $('.cb-content').each(function () {

        linksList.push(bodyHtml.find('a').text())
    });

    console.log(linksList);

  }
})
```

Comment: find('a').attr('href') instead, not text()

Answer (score 0):

Read `href` attribute value to get the link

```
inksList.push(bodyHtml.find('a').attr('href'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It should look more like this:

```
let linksList = $('.cb-content a').map((i, a) => {
  return $(a).attr('href')
}).get()
```